# android image size scale

Tags: android, image, layout

I need to add an image to the screen in a table row and have text over the image.

The image is a calendar with the date displayed on top. It work fine for the first device... see image here:

[image]

But get too small on the larger device... see image here:

[image]

the code is

```
RelativeLayout calender_image_text = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        ImageView imageview1 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        imageview1.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.calendar);
        imageview1.setPadding(00,00,00,00);
        //imageview1.setMaxHeight(150);
        //imageview1.setMaxWidth(150);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageview2param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(120, 80);
        imageview1param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        calender_image_text.addView(imageview1,imageview2param);
        //linearh1.addView(calender_image_text,tablerowparam00);

        TextView textview0 = new TextView(getActivity());
        textview0.setId(id_textview0);
        textview0.setText("Dec 0" + i);
        //textview0.setTextSize(12);
        textview0.setPadding(00,00,00,00);
        textview0.setSingleLine(false);
        textview0.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        //textview0.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        //textview0param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        //textview0param.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,imageview1.getId());
        //textview0param.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,imageview1.getId());
        //textview0param.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP,imageview1.getId());
        textview0param.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT,imageview1.getId());
        textview0.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textview0.setLayoutParams(textview0param);
        calender_image_text.addView(textview0,textview0param);
        linearh1.addView(calender_image_text,tablerowparam00);
```

Comment: show how you gave width and height to that image?//imageview1.setMaxHeight(150); using this or ?? any other way

Comment: I found nice AS modul for making icons http://stackoverflow.com/a/37321194/2360269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create different mipmap or drawable folder for different screen resolutions and place your images in it , here are drawable folder names

```
 drawables-ldpi  // for low density
 drawables-mdpi  //for medium density
 drawables-hdpi  //for high density
 drawables-xhdpi //for extra high density
 drawables-xxhdpi  //for extra extra high density
 drawables-xxxhdpi  //for extra extra extra high density
```

place your picture in all drawables with same name and android will pick images based on density of phone

your folders should be under res
  [like this](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-4329884d446f1f9246d61979487e9baf?convert_to_webp=true)

Answer (score 0):

You should create several folders for different screens, and create different images for them. (hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi and other you need)

Answer (score 0):

This layout should help you out ...

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/img_calendar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_date"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Dec 4"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```