# Background Image gets blurry when loaded into LinearLayout - Android

Tags: android, background-image, picasso

I have a background image with 4 diff dpi placed in different folders.

- drawable-xxhdpi contains 1630x1052
- drawable-xhdpi contains 970x609
- drawable-hdpi contains 603x402
- drawable-mhdpi contains 450x290

And here is the full resolution image: [image: Original Image]

But When I view this image in Android Application using mobile or tablet it becomes blurry as shown below.

[image: Background Image in Android]

I am loading this image using Picasso:

```
Picasso.with(drawFigure.this).load(R.drawable.back)
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)                 
.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(mCustomLayout);
```

Please correct me if anyone finds any mistake. Else, is there any any other way to show perfect image.
Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

> ```
>                        ldpi     mdpi     hdpi    xhdpi    xxhdpi       xxxhdpi
> Launcher And Home      36*36    48*48   72*72    96*96    144*144     192*192
> Toolbar And Tab        24*24    32*32   48*48    64*64    96*96       128*128
> Notification           18*18    24*24   36*36    48*48    72*72       96*96 
> Background             240*320  320*480 480*800  768*1280  1080 *1920  1440*2560
> ```

- minus Toolbar Size From total height of Background Screen and then Design Graphics of Screens.
  also you may refer https://design.google.com/devices/

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who donot want to create all images one by one can use Plugin described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37321194/7746337) in the answer by @erluxman.
I have tested it by myself and it is working fine.

Comment: This must be the selected answer.