# Choreogrpher Issues

Tags: java, android

I have problems with my app. It gives me the warning: I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

My app has 2 very simple activities in fact one of them I do not write its code. 1 of them is a splash screen with a progressBar and the other only show some elements.

**SplashScreen.java**

```
   public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variables declaration
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        //Fill in variables
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text_splash);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.splash_screen_progress_bar);

        //Change the textView font
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/ExpletusSans-BoldItalic.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(face);

        //Call to the background execution
        new UpdateProgressBar().execute();
    }

    /* Auxiliary class to operate in background:
    * First parameter: in data type of function doInBackground()
    * Second parameter: data type of function onProgressUpdate()
    * Third parameter: out data type of function doInBackground()
    * */
    public class UpdateProgressBar extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        //Execution in background (in a different thread)
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //I want to show splashScreen for 4 seconds
            for(int i = 1; i <= 4 ; i++){
                oneSecond();
                publishProgress(i*25);
                if(isCancelled()){
                    break;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        //It executes in the main thread, when I call publishProgress() in doInBackground().
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

        //Execute after doInBackground() in the main thread.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Intent change_screen = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MeasureScreenActivity.class);
            startActivity(change_screen);
            //Effect of transition
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in,R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
        }
    }

    //Auxiliary method to simulate one second
    public void oneSecond(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**splash_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="Breath Frequecy"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_screen_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300sp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img_loadpage" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/splash_screen_progress_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_progressbar_horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MeasureScreenActivity.java**

```
public class MeasureScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.measure_screen);
    }
}
```

**measure_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.appsgarci.prueba.MeasureScreenActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/app_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_measure"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:text="Elija la actividad que ha realizado:"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner_measure"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/spinner_measure"
        android:background="@drawable/stroke_spinner_selected"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_measure"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_measure"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_measure"
        android:layout_width="140sp"
        android:layout_height="140sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/action_button_shape"
        android:text="Iniciar"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Only with this code I already have the problem with Choreographer and I do not know why, because it only has one operation, that is upgrade the progressBar.

My drawable folder has this:

- action_button_shape.xml (v24)
- app_background.webp
- boton_measurement.webp (v24)
- boton_measurement_pressed.webp (v24)
- custom_progressbar.xml (v24)
- custom_progressbar_horizontal.xml
- img_loader.webp

I do not know the difference between drawable and drawable-24.

I have done several tests:

- In android studio emulator works perfectly (nexus_5x API 24)
- In my mobile phone gives me choreographer issue with and without drawable-24 elements(xiaomi mi max API 24)
- In another mobile phone I can't use drawable-24 but changing to drawable, it works fine (xiaomi redmi 3s API 23)

What could be happening in my mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned here [The application may be doing too much work on its main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread). You should also check the size of your drawables.

Try reducing size of images (`@drawable/app_background @drawable/img_loadpage`) or move them to `drawable-xxxhdpi` for now.

Comment: the size of them are 7,1KB and 37,1KB respectively. Is too much?

Comment: @SergioGarcia not really, but I would try what I suggested just to be sure

Comment: Its seems to work, this solution of moved all the images to drawable-xxxhdpi is a good practice? Anyway i have to probe it in mi whole app because this was only to "debug" the other jaja

Comment: @SergioGarcia might be a problem on older devices... But it should be  **super** ok if you use this [Android studio plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31275345/4858147) for importing png images. (try ignoring smaller one if it's too much work) I would also recommend vectorDrawable for icons.

Comment: Thanks so much because the problem was this. I probe it on my whole app and know works perfectly. What annoying thing, only move the images heavier than 1KB. Is not problem of older device because mine has only 1 year and the other device where I probed it is worst and older than mine so I do not know but know works. Thanks¡