# Assets Android and iOS from SVG

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, assets

I search a tool or app for create assets Android and iOS from an SVG file (for not lost resolution or quality).

For example, I have `my_img.svg` I use app and result a zip with :

iOS

`my_img@3x.png
my_img@2x.png
my_img.png`

Android

`hdpi/my_img.png
xhdpi/my_img.png
xxhdpi/my_img.png
...`

I work with Xamarin and I don't want use Android Studio and Xcode just for create assets.

Do you know app free or not for this, with SVG in source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android you can use [Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/)
It also helps to choose the right sizes for action bar icons, app icons, etc. As I'm not an iOS Dev I would just go along with the answer of Brayan Armando Yaquian Gonzale for that platform.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about [w3goodies](https://w3goodies.com/online-file-converter/svg-to-ios.html) for ios and [cloudconverter](https://cloudconvert.com/svg-to-png) for android?

Comment: Thx, w3goodies is good (but not android) and cloudconverter not export all format android in one file.

Comment: I do not know about something for Android, but with cloudconverter you can convert each resolution. Other solution can be Android Studio.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19196749/9253664) can help you

Comment: w3goodies (or your specific link in it) seems to be dead now :(